# Python Fabric is hanging

Tags: python, fabric

I've got an instance running on AWS EC2. Doing this:

```
    ssh -i keyname.pem user@box.com
```

Works!

Using Fabric to deploy my stuff now:

```
    fab -i keyname.pem -k deploy:host=user@box.com
```

Same key, same user/host, but it hangs miserably! No logging, just hangs.

Does anyone know how different are ssh settings that Fabric is trying to use from those in the system? I thought it is just wrap around SSH shell commands (I'm running all that from Cygwin if it matters). Completely stuck with this.

I've googled out a few threads where people complain about that, but all I found is recommendations to update Fabric. I have the newest one from cheese shop (Fabric v1.10.1, Paramiko v1.15.2), still this strange behavior to hang without saying anything.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to set env with all the information?

```
`from fabric.api import env
env.env_name = 'user'
env.key_filename = 'keyname.pem'
env.hosts = ['box.com']`
```

Answer (score 0):

I hit this same error before. Try ssh-ing into the server with ssh from terminal before using fabric. Sometimes is needs to be added to known-hosts, and fabric at times won't prompt you for this...